# Checking data between tables to see if they are equal

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to do a validation of the database tables of a mysql server, to see if they were changed, checking if there were changes comparing with the backup, but at the moment I'm doing comparing the timestamp checking when they were changed, is there any way to check comparing information with the backup for example if table x was changed after comparing with the data from the backup we saw that the data between tables was different.

Comment: Without knowing the size of the db, or how many tables are involved, but one possible way is to dump the data for both databases (or any specific tables) into separate files, and then run a diff utility on the two files to see the differences.

Comment: hey the db is a bit large and involves manny tables, but wich utility do you recommed,because my objective is to put this in a playbook

Answer (score 0):

If you have both tables you want to compare in the same database - the most accurate (but also pretty expensive) query would be:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table_to_validate
MINUS
SELECT
  *
FROM table_to_compare_with;
```

The query will return all rows in `table_to_validate` that don't have the exact same row in `table_to_compare_with` - or none at all if the tables are the same.

You can also run a reverse of that `MINUS` query to find rows that exist in the other table that don't exist in this table.

Comment: Thx for the help but in workbench MINUS doesn t work and i have two different databases wich each table is in different databases